# I'm known for being addictive

Tags: riddle

> I'm known for being addictive.
>   Children come to play inside.
>   You'll recognize my place once you see its emblem.
>   And when you leave I make you feel weird inside.
>   My ethics have been questioned.
>   So has my treatment of many.
>   But regardless of how much I slaughter.
>   People really don't mind.
>   When it comes to being known.
>   I'm in every country world wide.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> McDonald's

I'm known for being addictive.

> A lot of people say so

Children come to play inside.

> McDonald's PlayPlace

You'll recognize my place once you see its emblem.

> The golden arches are very recognizable

And when you leave I make you feel weird inside.

> You'll be full

My ethics have been questioned.
So has my treatment of many.

> McDonald's has a [long list of legal cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald's_legal_cases)

But regardless of how much I slaughter.
People really don't mind.

> McDonald's menus in all (?) countries have lots of meat on them. That's part of why many people eat there.

When it comes to being known.
I'm in every country world wide.

> McDonald's has restaurants in [over 100 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_McDonald's_restaurants), and in those it doesn't, it's surely still *known*

Comment: Or could be KFC. slaughter fits very well.

Comment: But there is no kids play thing with KFC I guess.

Comment: Will, you got it right. Also @me_digvijay Mope, the answer is MacDonalds.